# (Lightning) Show picklist value in Lightning Data Table

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a data Table in Lightning in which I am displaying record and for each record i have input picklist field which contain status value. I want to update status of all record in one go. But when I am selecting different status from picklist then new value is not getting passed in Controller.

Component:

```
<!--massUpdateAttendeeStatus-->
<aura:component access="global" controller="MassUpdateAttendeeStatusController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />.
    <aura:attribute name="relatedAttendees" type="MassUpdateAttendeeStatusController.wrapAttendeeRecord[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedAttendees" type="MassUpdateAttendeeStatusController.wrapAttendeeRecord[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="attendeeStatusList" type="String[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectAll" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedStatus" type="String"/>

    <style>
        .slds-modal__container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 450%;
        max-width: 66rem;
        min-width: 20rem;
        } 
    </style>  
    <div class="slds-page-header" role="banner">
        <div class="slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-media slds-no-space slds-grow">
                <div class="slds-media__figure">
                    <span class="slds-avatar slds-avatar--large">
                        <lightning:icon iconName="standard:drafts" alternativeText="Indicates approval" />
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-media__body">
                    <p class="slds-text-title--caps slds-line-height--reset">Attendees List</p>
                    <h1 class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate" title="Attendess Status">Mass Update Attendees Status</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><br/>
    <dl>
        <dd>&nbsp;Select Attendees record for which status need to be updated.</dd>
    </dl>
    <br/>
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                <th>
                    <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="box3" value="{!v.selectAll}" change="{!c.onCheck}"/>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Opportunity Name">Contact Name</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Status</div>

                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Opportunity Type">Notes</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.relatedAttendees}" var="atd">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="boxPack"  value="{!atd.attendeeSelected}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Contact Name">
                        <div class="slds-truncate slds-form-element__control" title="Cloudhub">
                            <p class="slds-hyphenate">{!atd.wrapAttendee.Contact__r.Name}</p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Attendee Status">
                        <ui:inputSelect  class="slds-select spear-select" aura:id="selectItem" value="{!atd.wrapAttendee.Status__c}" updateOn="change" >    
                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.attendeeStatusList}" var="stat">
                                <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!stat}" label="{!stat}" value="{!stat==atd.wrapAttendee.Status__c}" />            
                            </aura:iteration>    
                        </ui:inputSelect>
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!atd.wrapAttendee.Status__c == 'Attended'}">
                            <img src="{!$Resource.manageAttendeesImages + '/attended.gif'}"/>
                        </aura:if>&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Note">
                        <div class="slds-truncate slds-form-element__control" title="Cloudhub">
                            <lightning:textarea name="Note" value=""  maxlength="300"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-box_xx-small slds-box_xx-small-around_xx-small slds-size_1-of-1 slds-small-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_1-of-2 slds-align--center">
            <div >                
                <lightning:select name="selectItem" label="Attendees Status" value="{!v.selectedStatus}" onchange="{!c.setStatus}" >
                    <option text="None" value=""></option>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.attendeeStatusList}" var="stat">
                        <option text="{!stat}" value="{!stat}"></option>                    
                    </aura:iteration>                    
                </lightning:select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-docked-form-footer">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid--pull-padded">        
            <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-text-align--center">
                <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Create" onclick="{!c.changeStatus}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Java Script Controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getAllRelatedAttendees");  
        action.setParams({
            "visitRecordId" : component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {            
            component.set("v.relatedAttendees", a.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        helper.getPrepopulatedValues(component, event, helper);
    },

    onCheck: function(component, event, helper) {
        var selAll = component.get("v.selectAll");
        var newlst =[];    
        var allAttendees = component.get("v.relatedAttendees");
        for(var i in allAttendees){
            var space = allAttendees[i];                    
            space.attendeeSelected = selAll;             
            newlst.push(space);
        }
        component.set("v.selectedAttendees",newlst);
        component.set("v.relatedAttendees",newlst);
    },

    setStatus : function(component, event, helper) {
        var selcStatus = component.get("v.selectedStatus");
        var newlst =[];    
        var allAttendees = component.get("v.relatedAttendees");
        for(var i in allAttendees){
            var space = allAttendees[i];                    
            if(space.attendeeSelected === true){
                space.wrapAttendee.Status__c = selcStatus;             

            }
            newlst.push(space); 
        }
        component.set("v.relatedAttendees",newlst);
    }, 

    changeStatus : function(component, event, helper) {
        var allAttendees = component.get("v.relatedAttendees");
        for(var i in allAttendees){
            var space = allAttendees[i];    
            alert("$$$$:" + space.wrapAttendee.Status__c);
        }
    }
})


Helper:

({
    getPrepopulatedValues : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getStatusValues");
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {            
            component.set("v.attendeeStatusList", a.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Apex Controller:

```
public class MassUpdateAttendeeStatusController {
    @auraEnabled
    public static List<wrapAttendeeRecord> getAllRelatedAttendees(Id visitRecordId){
        List<wrapAttendeeRecord> wrapAttendeeRecordList = new List<wrapAttendeeRecord>();
        for(Attendee__c atd : [select Id, Contact__c, Contact__r.Name, Status__c, Notes__c from Attendee__c where Visit__c = :visitRecordId]){
            wrapAttendeeRecordList.add(new wrapAttendeeRecord(atd));
        }
        return wrapAttendeeRecordList;
    }

    @auraEnabled
    public static List<String> getStatusValues(){
        List<String> options = new List<String>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Attendee__c.Status__c.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
        for (Schema.PicklistEntry f: ple) {
            options.add(f.getLabel());
        }
        return options;
    }

    public class wrapAttendeeRecord{
        @auraEnabled
        public boolean attendeeSelected{get; set;}

        @auraEnabled
        public Attendee__c wrapAttendee{get; set;}

        @auraEnabled
        public boolean isAttended{get; set;}

        public wrapAttendeeRecord(Attendee__c atd){
            attendeeSelected = false;
            wrapAttendee = atd;
            if(atd.Status__c == 'Attended'){
                isAttended = true;
            }else{
                isAttended = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I use `<lightning:select>` with `value="{!v.value}"` attribute inside and it updates the value good

Comment: If you use it in Table then it will not update.

Comment: I see, I do you it in a table, but inside the table it is implemented inside another component, so this is why that works for me